# listview change to postion 0 when switch tab .

Tags: android, listview

i have a list in fragment show a list of photos .the parent is a ActiviyGroup , when i switch the tab to other Tab and back ,  and touch the list , the list will slip to the top .

i don't know why ? could anyone help me ?

bellow is the createview function of the fragment .

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.d(TAG,"call oncreate view!");
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_discovery, null);
mTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
mTitle.setText(R.string.discover);
mPullListView = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
mPullListView.setOnLastItemVisibleListener(this) ;
mPullListView.setOnRefreshListener(this) ;
mListView = mPullListView.getRefreshableView();
mListView.setAdapter(mPhotoAdapter);
mListView.addFooterView(mLoadMoreLayout);
init();
return view;
}
```

Comment: onCreateView is probably getting called whenever you change tab and that's recreating your listview

Comment: no , i see the log , it's not recreated .